# How to apply decorators to lambdas?

Tags: python, syntax, lambda, decorator

Is there any syntax for using a decorator on a lambda function in Python? Example:

```
def simpledecorator(f):
     def new_f():
         print "Using a decorator: "
         f()
     return  new_f

@simpledecorator
def hello():
    print "Hello world!"
```

Results in this output:

```
>>> hello()
Using a simple decorator:
Hello world!
```

Yet when I try the same with a lambda:

```
@anotherdecorator
f = lambda x: x * 2
```

I get this:

```
  File "<stdin", line 2
    f = lambda x: x * 2
    ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I feel like this might be a good way to make lambdas more versatile by allowing statements to be "injected" into them. But if there exists such a feature, I don't know what the syntax is.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
f = anotherdecorator(lambda x: x * 2)
```

Comment: I wish I had thought of that earlier. It does avoid the situation that the `@decorator` syntax seeks to fight i.e. `f = anotherdecorator(f)`. Still, this is a very useful language feature.

Comment: Before `@` syntax, something like this was the main way to decorate a function (or class).

Comment: Syntax error , remove the return f = anotherdecorator(lambda x: x * 2)

Answer (score 2):

There appear to be two options which give the functionality, but without the clean syntax:

(1) Keep `lambda` and ditch the decorator syntax (as posted by dan04):

`f = simpledecorator( lambda : print( "Hello World" ) )`

(2) Keep the decorator syntax and use a 1 line `def` statement instead of lambda:

```
@simpledecorator
def f(): print ( "Hello World" )
```

This 2nd form may be preferable if you want to chain decorators:

```
@simpledecorator
@simpledecorator
def f(): print ( "Hello World" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying the above using the [retry-decorator](https://pypi.org/project/retry-decorator/) only gave me syntax errors.

This what I found to be working:

```
import shutil
from retry_decorator import retry
diskfree = retry(
    FileNotFoundError,
    timeout_secs = 10,
  )(lambda d: shutil.disk_usage(d))(d="/")
```